# Not displaying breadcrumbs in Contacts page

Tags: layout, contact-us, magento1.9.2.3

In my site, the breadcrumbs are not displaying on the Contacts page. I have added the code for breadcrumbs in contacts.xml (given below), but still not working.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<contacts_index_index translate="label">
    <label>Contact Us Form</label>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts">
            <title>Contact Us</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs">
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>home</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo>
                <label>Home</label>
                <title>Home</title>
                <link>/</link>
            </crumbInfo>
        </action> 
        <action method="addCrumb">
            <crumbName>contacts</crumbName>
            <crumbInfo>
                <label>Contact us</label>
                <title>Contact us</title>
            </crumbInfo>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts">
            <title>Contact Us</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <update handle="cms_menu"/>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code should work** if breadcrumb `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>` have been called at `2columns-left.phtml`.

Or you have not **removed** `breadcrumbs` from  **layout xml files**.

**A short solution is:**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code in contact

```
<reference name="root">
  <action method="unsetChild"><alias>breadcrumbs</alias></action>
  <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="addCrumb">
      <crumbName>home</crumbName>
      <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
    </action> 
    <action method="addCrumb">
      <crumbName>contacts</crumbName>
      <crumbInfo><label>Contact us</label><title>Contact us</title></crumbInfo>
    </action>
  </block>
</reference>
```